# sending data from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send some String Data from sub activity to main activity and show that data in edit text field.
Here is my code in sub activity :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setClass(getApplicationContext(),
        DelaySmsActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("values", stringDataForSend);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, in);                   
        finish();
    }
});
```

and here is code from main activity where I'm trying to get that value:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    parametar = data.getStringExtra("values");
    editTextField.setText(parametar);
}
```

after I run this my editTextField is empty.

Comment: are you sure you are calling the second activity using startActivityForResult ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lets say your present activity is X and Next Activity is Y :-

```
   Intent main= new Intent(X.this, Y.class);
   main.putExtra("key", "somevalue");
   X.this.startActivity(main);
```

At Y Activity onCreate

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String value= intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Answer (score 3):

For passing simple data, like strings, I use Bundles instead.

In your onClick:

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
Bundle yourBundle = new Bundle();
yourBundle.putString("name", string);
yourIntent.putExtra(yourBundle);
startActivity(yourIntent);
```

Then, in your next activity's onCreate, retrieve your string like:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String passedValue = bundle.getString("name");
```

Comment: no there is not use writing that code in your onCreate method. You have to get it from the 'Intent data' of your activitie's onActivityResult.

Comment: Sure, if you choose to use startActivityForResult. But for simple things like passing a string, why make it more complicated?

Comment: you forget the fact that the question is how to pass a value back to its parent activity, not to a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

since you are not submitting your code here is an example that should help you

**When you call the activity use `startActivityForResult() not startActivity()`**

```
public class CheckStartActivityForResult extends Activity {
     int requestCode;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("CheckStartActivity","OnCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,CalledActivity.class);       
        startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("CheckStartActivity","onActivityResult and resultCode = "+resultCode);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and the called activity

```
public class CalledActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("CalledActivity","OnCreate ");
        //String value = "rahul";
        Intent in = new Intent();
        setResult(1,in);//Here I am Setting the Requestcode 1, you can put according to your requirement
        finish();
    }

}
```